# laravel-notification-channels / telegram Обработка исключений

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot

Использую laravel-notification-channels / telegram для создания бота. У меня есть список пользователей, которым нужно отправить сообщение:

```
$users = User::where('telegram_id', '<>', null)->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
$user->notify(new TelegramNotification($message));
```

Столкнулся с проблемой: если пользователь остановил и заблокировал бота, то ловится ошибка

```
403 - Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user
```

Хотел поставить обработку ошибок, чтобы отлавливать все ошибки 4xx, записыватьв  логи и пропускать, но мне не удаётся этого сделать.

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return [TelegramChannel::class];
}

public function toTelegram($notifiable)
{
        $data    = $this->getData();
        $message = TelegramMessage::create()
            ->to($notifiable->getTelegramId());
        if (isset($data['text'])) {
            $message->content($data['text']);
            if (!empty($data['url'])) {
                $url = url($data['url']);
                $message->button('Показать товар в системе', $url);
            }
        }
    try {
        return $message;
    } catch (CouldNotSendNotification $exception){
        Log::error('Не удалось отправить сообщение пользователю. ' . $exception);
    }
}
```

Пробовал вместо CouldNotSendNotification ставить ClientException, но это не помогло, catch не отрабатывает. Есть ли способ решить это? Нужно делать запись в логи и продолжать выполнение, а не останавливаться и выводить экран ошибки

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  $user->notify(new TelegramNotification($message));
} catch (CouldNotSendNotification $e) {
  report ($e);
}
```

В методе `register` обработчика исключений `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` добавляем обработчик:

```
$this->reportable(function (CouldNotSendNotification $e) {
  // здесь пишем логи
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно то, что мне нужно